# How do I display the content of closest <td> on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have looked everywhere, but my code does not work at all. I simply want to display the content of the td I'm clicking on.

I have this table:

```
<tr class='rowData' tooltip='{caracteristicas}'>
  <td nowrap class='Body'><a href='{caracteristicas}' target="_blank" style="color:black" onClick='return confirm("VOCÊ SERÁ REDIRECIONADO PARA:\r\r {caracteristicas}")'>{inputDescItem}</a></td>
  <td nowrap class='Body' align='right'>{quantidade} {hiddenCodigoItem}</td>
  <td nowrap class='Body' align='center'>{grupoEstoque}</td>
  <td nowrap class='Body' align='center'>{inputCodigoItem}</td>
  <td nowrap class='Body' align='center'>{btnAtualizaItem}</td>
  <td nowrap class='Body' align='center'><button type="button" class="btnTest">Assign</button></td>
  <td nowrap class='Body' align='center' class="testNameClass" name="output" style="display:none;">{caracteristicas}</td>
</tr>
```

I want it so that when I click on the CLICK ME  tag, it will display (in a pop-up, alert, modal or anything) the content of the below tag (that I'm not displaying).

I have the following javascript:

```
$("btnTest").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('testNameClass').val());
});
```

I'm not very good at JS so please go easy on me.

Comment: Your html is not having any 'Click Me' tag. Can you update the details

Answer (score 4):

Look like you missing
**$(".btnTest")** instead of $("btnTest")
and just try

```
$(".btnTest").on("click", function() {
alert($(this).parents('tr').find('.testNameClass').val());
});
```

Comment: i just tried it,i get ''undefined'' as result no matter what

Answer (score 1):

To target specific elements using a `class` you need to use a dot in front of the class name. In your case `.btnTest` and `.testNameClass`.

```
$(".btnTest").on("click", function() {
 alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.testNameClass').text());
});
```

As you are looking for the text inside the td element you should use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

In the below example column **ent_3** is hidden and you will get its values using the script mentioned above.

```js
$(".btnTest").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.testNameClass').text());
});
```

```css
.testNameClass {
  display: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>pk</th>
            <th>ent_1</th>
            <th>ent_2</th>
            <th>ent_3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>PK Row 0</td>
          <td>Ent_1</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btnTest">Assign</button></td>
          <td class="testNameClass">Row 0 Ent_3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>PK Row 1</td>
          <td>Ent_1</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btnTest">Assign</button></td>
          <td class="testNameClass">Row 1 Ent_3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>PK Row 2</td>
          <td>Ent_1</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btnTest">Assign</button></td>
          <td class="testNameClass">Row 2 Ent_3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method will be handed a reference to the `MouseEvent` which represents details of the click.  Since it is an `Event`, it has a `currentTarget` which represents an "element" in the so-called DOM ... an internal data-structure which represents the HTML.  This data structure is in the form of a tree, where each node has one parent, two siblings, and some children.  You can now write code to "walk up the tree" until you encounter a `td` node.  The first one you come to is the innermost containing `td`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are targeting is incorrect use a . before the class name - also I see two classes in one element I set this up for you here have a look

https://jsfiddle.net/hw0ansyj/1/

```
$(".btnTest").on("click", function() {
    alert($('.testNameClass').html());
});
```